# Python/Pyscript Erro with folium

Tags: python, html, folium, pyscript

i'm trying to make a simple code with pyScript and the folium library, but I'am continually getting this error

```
[pyscript/base] PythonError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/lib/python3.10/asyncio/futures.py", line 201, in result
    raise self._exception
  File "/lib/python3.10/asyncio/tasks.py", line 232, in __step
    result = coro.send(None)
  File "/lib/python3.10/site-packages/_pyodide/_base.py", line 506, in eval_code_async
    await CodeRunner(
  File "/lib/python3.10/site-packages/_pyodide/_base.py", line 357, in run_async
    coroutine = eval(self.code, globals, locals)
  File "<exec>", line 3, in <module>
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script defer src="https://pyscript.net/latest/pyscript.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pyscript.net/latest/pyscript.css" />
   
    <py-env>
        - folium
    </py-env>
   
    <title>pyscipt test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="map" style="width: 100%; height: 100%"></div>

    <py-script output="map">
import folium as fpl

m = fpl.map(location=[-6.2238, 106.8193], zoom_start=10)

print(m)
    </py-script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do the Folium examples work for you? Start there & then build in your changes. I say this because your code already seem outdated. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74131753/8508004) about `<py-env>` which you use being deprecated in favor of `<py-config>` which the official Folium example [here](https://pyscript.net/examples/folium.html) uses. This [comment here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74131494/8508004): "As it develops, some things in PyScript are moving targets", & the closing statement at the bottom may give you a sense things are changing rapidly.

Comment: I think `fpl.map(...)` should be `fpl.Map(...)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code needs some update and corrections. Try this modified code.

```html
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <script defer src="https://pyscript.net/latest/pyscript.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pyscript.net/latest/pyscript.css" />
       
    <py-config>
packages = [
  "folium",
]
    </py-config>
       
        <title>pyscript test: Success!</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="map" style="width: 100%; height: 100%"></div>

        <py-script output="map">
    import folium as fpl

    m = fpl.Map(location=[-6.2238, 106.8193], zoom_start=10)
    fpl.LayerControl().add_to(m)
    m
        </py-script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Some warning from `pyscript` site:-

> Please be advised that PyScript is very alpha and under heavy
> development. There are many known issues, from usability to loading
> times, and you should expect things to change often. We encourage
> people to play and explore with PyScript, but at this time we do not
> recommend using it for production.