# Error after pyscript update with a simple example code

Tags: python-3.x, pyscript

I don't know if this error is due to a PyScript update, I would like to know how to solve it.

With previous versions there are no problems running the code using the following CDNs:

```html
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pyscript.net/alpha/pyscript.css" />

    <script defer src="https://pyscript.net/alpha/pyscript.js"></script>
```

The error occurs when I use the latest updated version (see CDNs) in the code below:

```html
<html>

<head>

    <title> Learn DOM for PyScript </title>

    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' media='screen' href='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bulma@0.9.3/css/bulma.min.css'>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pyscript.net/latest/pyscript.css" />

    <script defer src="https://pyscript.net/latest/pyscript.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

<h1>Learn DOM Manipulation using PyScript</h1>

<h2>Simple String Counter using Python </h2>

<br>

<p>Input Text</p>

<textarea name="input_text" id="input_text" placeholder="Enter your text...."></textarea>

<br>

<button id="run" type="button" class="button is-primary" pys-onClick="count">Count</button>
<button id="clear" type="button" class="button is-danger" pys-onClick="clear">Clear</button>

<p>Output from </p>

<p id = 'output'></p>
    
</body>

<py-script>

input_text = Element("input_text")    

op = Element("output")

def clear(*args, **kwargs):
    input_text.clear()

def count(*args, **kwargs):
    number = len(input_text.value)
    op.write(number)


</py-script>


</html>
```

I don't know what this error is due to, can someone please help.

---

This is the error:

```
pyscript.ts:199 Use of pys-onClick and pys-onKeyDown attributes is deprecated in favor of py-onClick() and py-onKeyDown(). pys-on* attributes will be deprecated in a future version of PyScript.
createElementsWithEventListeners @ pyscript.ts:199
initHandlers @ pyscript.ts:186
initialize @ runtime.ts:88
await in initialize (async)
(anonymous) @ pyconfig.ts:107
load (async)
loadRuntimes @ pyconfig.ts:106
connectedCallback @ pyconfig.ts:70
(anonymous) @ main.ts:20
(anonymous) @ main.ts:26
pyodide.asm.js:10 Uncaught (in promise) PythonError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/lib/python3.10/asyncio/futures.py", line 201, in result
    raise self._exception
  File "/lib/python3.10/asyncio/tasks.py", line 232, in __step
    result = coro.send(None)
  File "/lib/python3.10/site-packages/_pyodide/_base.py", line 506, in eval_code_async
    await CodeRunner(
  File "/lib/python3.10/site-packages/_pyodide/_base.py", line 357, in run_async
    coroutine = eval(self.code, globals, locals)
  File "<exec>", line 3, in <module>
NameError: name 'count' is not defined

    at new_error (pyodide.asm.js:10:218127)
    at pyodide.asm.wasm:0xdef7c
    at pyodide.asm.wasm:0xe37ae
    at method_call_trampoline (pyodide.asm.js:10:218041)
    at pyodide.asm.wasm:0x126317
    at pyodide.asm.wasm:0x1f6f2e
    at pyodide.asm.wasm:0x161a32
    at pyodide.asm.wasm:0x126827
    at pyodide.asm.wasm:0x126921
    at pyodide.asm.wasm:0x1269c4
    at pyodide.asm.wasm:0x1e0697
    at pyodide.asm.wasm:0x1da6a5
    at pyodide.asm.wasm:0x126a07
    at pyodide.asm.wasm:0x1e248c
    at pyodide.asm.wasm:0x1e00d9
    at pyodide.asm.wasm:0x1da6a5
    at pyodide.asm.wasm:0x126a07
    at pyodide.asm.wasm:0xe347a
    at Module.callPyObjectKwargs (pyodide.asm.js:10:119006)
    at Module.callPyObject (pyodide.asm.js:10:119387)
    at wrapper (pyodide.asm.js:10:183751)
```

Taking this error into account, I corrected the code by substituting
pys-onClick by py-onClick(). The error goes away but now the code doesn't work.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and post the [*full text* of any errors or tracebacks](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359146).

Comment: Show error details from the browser debugger Console and Network tabs.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution in the documentation, the problem is that the old ways of declaring the button are deprecated. For current versions onwards it is recommended to use: `<button py-click="function()">`

Finally to solve the problem use:

```
<button id="run" py-click="count()">Count</button>
<button id="clear" py-click="clear()">Clear</button>
```

Comment: Can you point to specific examples you reference with" solution in the documentation,"? I see what you show [in the example here](https://pyscript.net/examples/todo.html), but  I'm seeing a different syntax [here](https://docs.pyscript.net/latest/reference/API/display.html?highlight=py%20onclick) **at present**: `<button id="my-button" py-onClick="display_hello()">Click me</button>`. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74131494/8508004) seems to match docs now. [The example here](https://pyscript.net/examples/todo-pylist.html) uses a different approach though so maybe there's several right now.